# Stopping an executable running if vbs loop if outside criteria is met

Tags: vbscript

I'm using a VBScript to write into a configuration file *config.txt*, then run an executable *SomeName.exe* with the configuration I set.
The excecutable is not mine, I cannot interact with it.
The result is written in another text file *Result.txt*.

In the end, it looks like this

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For MyParameter = mystart to myend
   
   'here I overwrite conf.txt with MyParameter value
   Rt = objShell.run(SomeName.exe, 1, True) '--> True means "wait until the end before processing"

Next
```

What I'd like to do is to check the result.txt file and, if it's ok, stop the .exe and resume the loop with next value of MyParameter.

I already know how to read the file and decide whether the result is good enough or not (basically I read the last line and compare it with something else, very easy stuff) with a second script.

What I don't know is how to make this two scripts work together.

For now the only way I have is to run manually my second script and make it check from time to time (with `Sleep` function) if the result is good. In that case, I use `taskill /im "SomeName.exe"`. But it's quite ugly and I have to run it with an infinite loop since I don't know how long it will take to SomeName.exe to reach the result (it's a simulation, it can be very very long !).

Have you got any idea on how to do that ?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help you can give me,

Comment: Why use WaitOnReturn=True?  Change that to False and then add your script code loop that checks for final line right after it.

Comment: oh god, why was I looking for something more complexe ? Thanks a lot, I'll try this and let you know if it does the trick.

Comment: Sure - I'll put into an answer and please mark it as correct if it works for you

Comment: I had couple others issues but your answer helped a lot, many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `WaitOnReturn=True`?

Change that to False and then add your script code loop that checks for final line right after it.

Comment: Perfect ! I feel quite stupid not having think about it by myself.
Thanks a lot